# Custom handler search filter table antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd to create a table with filter feature,
but I got a problem, I want to custom filter search of antd to call api,

[antd table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Djwc.png)

How can I do that with react and antd,

Here is my code

```
const columns: ColumnsType<Product> = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      render: (name, record) => (
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <Avatar src={record.avatar}>{name[0].toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
          <span style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} className="whitespace-nowrap">
            <a title="View & Edit" href={'/product/' + record.id}>
              {name}
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      dataIndex: 'about',
      key: 'about',
      render: (about: string) => <p className="text-ellipsis line-clamp-2">{about}</p>,
      width: 400,
    },
    {
      title: 'Categories',
      dataIndex: 'categories',
      key: 'categories',
      filterSearch: true,
      filters: categories!.map((category: Category) => ({ text: category.name, value: category.id })),

      render: (categories: any) => {
        console.log(categories);

        return '-';
      },
      // width: 400,
    },
    { title: 'Addresses', dataIndex: 'contract_addresses', key: 'address', render: addresses => addresses?.[0] },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the table, I usually provide a function that filters the data before it is passed to the table (In my example the function `getData`. This function can also be used to adjust the filter accordingly. Here is an example, which also consists of a Search-Input to modify the search:

```
const CustomersTable = (props: any) => {

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<ICustomer[]>([]);

  const getData = (
    sourceData: Array<ICustomer>,
    searchText: string | undefined
  ) => {
    if (!searchText) {
      return sourceData;
    }
    return sourceData.filter((item) => {
      const comparisonString = `${item.firstname.toLowerCase()}${item.familyname.toLowerCase()}`;

      //here you can provide a more sophisticared search
      return comparisonString.includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
    });
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Vorname",
      dataIndex: "firstname",
      key: "firstname",
      sorter: (a: ICustomer, b: ICustomer) => {
        if (a.firstname.toLowerCase() > b.firstname.toLowerCase()) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a.firstname.toLowerCase() < b.firstname.toLowerCase()) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Nachname",
      dataIndex: "familyname",
      key: "familyname",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Search
        placeholder="Vorname, Nachname"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={getData(customers, searchText)}
      />
      </>
  );

};
```